# Restrict malicious html but allow < or > symbols

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to restrict malicious html entered by a user, but it should be allowed that the user uses the greater than (>) or less than (<) symbols.

Is it safe to just disallow the following two strings?

```
"/>" and "</"
```

Can any malicious html be executed without closing tags?

Some more info: this is ASP.Net MVC, the user enters some text in a textbox, the text is stored in the database and then it is displayed on the page.

Comment: Please describe entire situation: programming language, use-case (POST request, information stored in DB, loaded file etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation can also be handled by escaping the input your user has entered when it is displayed on the user interface.  This will cause all user input to be displayed as text on the ui.  In this case tags would not be rendered on the browser for user input.

Answer (score 1):

Every user input must be processed without removing any data. You should use escaping when showing it to user if you aware of harming.

There is a lot of technics to circumvent dumb find/replace filters. Read about xss vulnerability and sql injection.